# Eliminate a variable from two equations with trigonometric functions

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to eliminate theta from the following two equations but in vain. I tried the command Eliminate and Reduce.

```
 eqn={0 == (p^2 \[Epsilon]^2 (a^3 \[Kappa]1 \[Mu] + 4 a \[Kappa]2 \[Mu] + 
 4 F \[Gamma] \[Omega]n0 Sin[\[Theta]]))/(8 \[Omega]n0^2), 
  0 == -((p (8 a^3 \[Kappa]1 (p \[Kappa]2 + 2 \[Omega]n0^2) + 
  16 a \[Kappa]2 (p \[Kappa]2 + 4 \[Omega]n0^2) + 
  a^5 p (\[Kappa]1^2 + 4 kappa \[Omega]n0^2) + 
  64 F p \[Gamma] \[Epsilon]^2 \[Omega]n0^2 Cos[\[Theta]]))/(
 128 a \[Omega]n0^3))};
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How about solving for $\theta$ from first equation and plug this in the second equation.  And do the same, solve for $\theta$ from the second equation and plug the solution in the first equation?

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for the suggestion, but doing so will solve the first equation as arcsine which is not very helpful to use in the second equation.

Comment: Well, but it eliminates $\theta$ from the equations which is what you asked for.  May be someone else will have better suggestions.

Comment: I think I was able to solve it, the trick is to change sin and cos to exponential and then replace them with a variable x as below: Eliminate[(eqn // TrigToExp) /. E^(I \[Theta]) -> xx /. 
  E^(-I \[Theta]) -> 1/xx, xx]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. Here is your system:

```
eqn = {0 == (p^2 e^2 (a^3 k1 m + 4 a k2 m + 4 F g w Sin[t]))/(8 w^2), 
  0 == -((p (8 a^3 k1 (p k2 + 2 w^2) + 16 a k2 (p k2 + 4 w^2) + 
          a^5 p (k1^2 + 4 k w^2) + 
          64 F p g e^2 w^2 Cos[t]))/(128 a w^3))}
```

To increase its visibility, I replaced the Greek letters by the Latin ones.

Now, this resolves the equations with respect to sin and cos, and then transforms each solution to a list:

```
lst1 = Map[Power[#, 2] &, List @@ Solve[eqn[[1]], Sin[t]][[1, 1]]]
lst2 = Map[Power[#, 2] &, List @@ Solve[eqn[[2]], Cos[t]][[1, 1]]]

(*  {Sin[t]^2, ((a^3 k1 + 4 a k2)^2 m^2)/(16 F^2 g^2 w^2)}

{Cos[t]^2, (
 a^2 (a^4 k1^2 p + 8 a^2 k1 k2 p + 16 k2^2 p + 16 a^2 k1 w^2 + 
    64 k2 w^2 + 4 a^4 k p w^2)^2)/(4096 e^4 F^2 g^2 p^2 w^4)}  *)
```

This eliminates the functions of the angle:

```
(MapThread[Plus, {lst1, lst2}] // Simplify) /. List -> Equal

(*  1 == (256 (a^3 k1 + 4 a k2)^2 m^2 w^2 + (8 a^3 k1 (k2 p + 2 w^2) + 
    16 a k2 (k2 p + 4 w^2) + a^5 p (k1^2 + 4 k w^2))^2/(e^4 p^2))/(
 4096 F^2 g^2 w^4)  *)
```

Done. Have fun!